# .bat file exits immediately after executing first sdfx command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

We have a batch script (windows) that creates a Scratch ORG and installs the packaging, licensing and setting we need for development/testing. It is failing in a particular machine (working fine in others). The behavior we are seeing is that it executes correctly but it force closes the window/process preventing the rest of the script to execute. Any suggestion/ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
set /p projectName="Enter a project name: "
set /p orgName="Enter a scratch org name: "
set /p orgLife="Enter scratch org lifespan in days (7-30): "
echo.
set mypath=%~dp0
echo %mypath:~0,-1%
echo %mypath:~0,-1%\%projectName%\config\project-scratch-def.json
echo Creating SFDX Project..
sfdx force:project:create -n %projectName% --template standard  //STEP #1 of the script EXITS
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick guesses as I'm not on my laptop:
- if "sfdx" really is "sfdx.cmd" then
- try "call sfdx..."

Comment: That did the trick! Can you elaborate a bit more for me to give you the right answer reward? What is the difference between sfdx (cli command) vs sfdx.cmd? Why would the machine have the second as opposed to the first (like the other machines)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: .cmd is a batch file just like .bat. We need to "call".cmd and .bat in order to "return". In this case when you type sfdx, the sfdx.cmd gets executed as there is no sfdx.exe or sfdx.com. You can locate sfdx.cmd and look what's inside it.

Comment: My confusion stems from other machines that also have the Salesforce CLI installed, and not seeing this behavior. I'm assuming I created the .cmd and didn't remember.